# Magento 2 - Type format catalog admin grid

Tags: magento2, admin

We have two questions about the catalog grid in Magento 2:

- By default there is a qty column, but this value has a dot and 4 zero's behind it. How can we show just the rounded value?
- We've added the 'Cost Price' column, but this is not shown as a price. How can we format this column as price.

See: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fy5sfgxerg7ugp9/Schermafbeelding%202017-12-05%20om%2010.31.29.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

I have created module for this.

Fellow below steps:

**Step:1** Create `registration.php` file at location

> app\code\AR\CustomCatalog\

and add below code

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'AR_CustomCatalog',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Setp:2** Create `module.xml` file at location

> app\code\AR\CustomCatalog\etc\

and add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2015 Ccc. All rights reserved.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="AR_CustomCatalog" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
            <module name="Magento_CatalogInventory"/>
        </sequence>
   </module>
</config>
```

**Step:3** Create `product_listing.xml` file at location

> app\code\AR\CustomCatalog\view\adminhtml\ui_component

and add below code in file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="product_columns" class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="qty" class="AR\CustomCatalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Quantity">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Quantity</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">75</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="cost" class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Price">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Cost</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">80</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**Step:4** Create `Quantity.php` file at location

> app\code\AR\CustomCatalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns

and add below code in file

```
<?php

namespace AR\CustomCatalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;

class Quantity extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{
    /**
     * Column name
     */
    const NAME = 'column.qty';

    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                if (isset($item[$fieldName])) {
                    $item[$fieldName] = round($item[$fieldName] ,0);
                }
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

**setp:5** run command `bin/magento setup:upgrade` and check